# How to configure "global pipeline libraries"?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm following [Using global library in pipeline](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/jenkins-workflow-using-global-library-implement-re-usable-function-call-secured-http-endpoint) and [Pipeline Shared Libraries](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin/blob/master/README.md). Seems like there is a way to configure "global pipeline scripts" for a jenkins instance.

The documentation says the configuration is "Manage Jenkins » Configure System » Global Pipeline Libraries".

However, the Jenkins 2.7.2 instance doesn't have "Global Pipeline Libraries" configuration. I am looking for how to configure "Global Pipeline Libraries" ?

Answer (score 3):

Just ran into the same thing.  The option to add external repos is new, update the Shared Groovy Libraries plugin to 2.3 and you'll be in business.

Comment: Is this the plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Groovy+Plugin ?

Comment: It is this plugin that needs updating: [Pipeline Shared Groovy Libraries Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Shared+Groovy+Libraries+Plugin). Gene's solution worked for me.